# Not able to map all the product variations fields in commerce feeds importer

Tags: commerce, feeds

I have one content type and added one field Product Variations' as product reference with widget 'Inline entity form - Multiple values'. But when I used Node Processor, I am not able to map other fields of the product variations. It only shows SKU and Product ID fields in target drop-down. It shows all the fields from node but not from the product variations.

Because of this I am not able to add more fields in my CSV file except title and sku.
Does anyone have any ideas on this?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I can't understand what's your setup and what you are actually trying to do. Try to read your own question like if you had no idea what it's about. Is it clear? If no, please edit. If yes, well, then it's just me.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Another user gave me this to answer my question:

[How to use Commerce Feeds to Import Stock for the Commerce Stock module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/169475/how-do-i-use-drupal-7-commerce-feeds-to-import-stock-for-commerce-stock/169562#169562)

The user https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/8943/watergate suggested this:

1. If you're using commerce_feeds 7.x-1.3, uninstall it.
2. Make sure you've updated the standard Drupal feeds to 7.x-2.0-beta1
3. Download commerce_feeds 7.x-1.x-dev

After I did that, I could use mapping and see all the target fields for my product variation, including those fields enabled when you use commerce_stock.