# How to use Commerce Feeds to Import Stock for the Commerce Stock module?

Tags: 7, commerce, feeds

I have the [Commerce Stock](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_stock) module enabled for my products in [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce).

But I cannot import data to the stock fields: When I set up the correct product processor, I can't see the Stock field which is present in my product variation type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem sounds similar to the issue: [Not recognizing product variants fields](https://www.drupal.org/node/2507109).

The solution is most probably to upgrade the [Commerce Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_feeds) module to 7.x-1.x-dev, or if you don't want to use a dev version you could downgrade the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module to 7.x-2.0-alpha9.

Comment: Thank you!  It shows the fields I want to use now.  If something ends up not working like I thought it would, I've still got my local copies of Drupal and my database structure.

Comment: Upgrading commerce feeds didn't work for me, but downgrading feeds to 7.x-2.0-alpha9 did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As for me there was only one solution: reinstall. And after reinstalling first you should add importer, set stock mapping and only after that - enable feeds tamper. If I installed tamper before mapping setup there always was same problem with mapping. So, mb it's same thing. Sorry, can't comment.

Comment: I actually had to manually pull out my commerce_feeds 7.x-1.3 because each time I disabled and "uninstalled," commerce_feeds was still there.  But I've got the 7.x-1.x-dev, and the mapping shows the field targets I wanted.